# why my tomcat which on centos is too slow when I access it

Tags: tomcat, centos

I install tomcat on centos  in my vmware machine.
When I access tomcat at my windows firefox,it's too slow.
I edit the iptables and add "8080" port to access in it, like this:
"-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT"
Then i restart the tomcat.
It very slow at my windows7 firefox explore.While if i close the iptables ,it will be fine.But it's not safe.
So who can tell me why and what I should do to increase the speed to access tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Tomcat needs at least 2cpu and 2GB memory. That would be my first test. If that helps then you can adjust them appropriately according to your application

Comment: but after I stop the iptables and then visit tomcat by my host computer,it very fast.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others - I had a similar problem that tomcat appeared to be slow(for apparently no reason) when accessed inside the CentOS(I am not talking about the case when it is accessed outside the CentOS). It turned out that tomcat wasn't slow, but the incorrect proxy settings in firefox was making it appear slow. i changed the proxy settings to manual, and configured no proxy required for localhost and restarted the browser. My problem went away instantly.